# Lookup password value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro set up to password protect a file that is created from the same macro. This works fine, but I want to use this when separate files are generated for different recipients, and the recipients should all have unique passwords.

How would I look up the password value from a separate spreadsheet when saving the files via the macro?

At the minute my code looks like this with a preset password (file path/name shortened for ease).

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "filepath\filename" , FileFormat:= _xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:= "Test"
```

This works, but I want the password to be replaced by a value that is looked up from another spreadsheet. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adapt this to your specific needs, but something like this should give you a start:

```vb
Sub testLookup()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim arrRecipients: arrRecipients = ws.Range("A1:B" & lRow) 'assume path in col A, password col B

For R = LBound(arrRecipients) To UBound(arrRecipients)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=arrRecipients(R, 1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:=arrRecipients(R, 2)
Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! All sorted now with a bit of tweaking.